# Can AWS Toolkit in IntellIJ be used with localstack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, local, localstack

I am trying to use the plugin AWS Toolkit (IntelliJ) with localstack, but I do not see any option or configuration file to include localstack endpoint/configuration. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not implemented in AWS toolkit plugin yet. See https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/1883